# Automate Restart Of Solr

Tags: linux

I have 3 instance of solr running

1. using tomcat (in shell u will find something like -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-6.0.35 -)
2. suing tomcat_1 (in shell u will find something like -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-6.0.35_1 -)
3. using tomcat_2 (in shell u will find something like -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-6.0.35_2 -)

Can i write a shell script which can kill the particular instance

1. for 1 : kill tomcat but not tomcat_1 & tomcat_2
2. for 2 : kill tomcat_1 but not tomcat & tomcat_2
3. for 3 : kill tomcat_2 but not tomcat & tomcat_1

Comment: Sure you can. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2):

<sub>When I wrote this answer four years ago, I was still a Linux and shell novice — and the original answer with all its unnecessary `grep`ing and `sed`ing makes that painfully obvious…</sub>
<sub>There is of course a much simpler solution:</sub>

```
pkill -f 'tomcat-6.0.35 '
```

will send SIGTERM to all processes whose *full commandline* (= the name of the executable + the parameters it has been launched with — hence the `-f`) contains the string 'tomcat-6.0.35 '. Make sure to include the trailing space to avoid matching 'tomcat-6.0.35_1' etc.

You can also use `pgrep` instead of `pkill` to list the process IDs instead of directly SIGTERM-ing them.